# Is there a good reason to use a fictional country in a world with an alternate earth?

Tags: world-building, historical-fiction, alternative-history

Is there a good reason to use a fictional country in a world with an alternate earth? I see a lot of TV show where we have an alternate history on earth and where we see Russian, American people speaking English, German etc. set in an universe with just a slightly alternate history, but we sometimes use a fictional country in the Middle East instead of using an existing country like Iraq. Is there a reason why this is done? I am not sure if I want to use a fictional country, because it would make the story less interesting, at least to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do that to keep from offending actual countries, or the people from there, or people whose ancestors are from there. They may accuse you of racism, or religious bigotry, or using hateful stereotypes.

You use a fictional country so you don't get boycotted, or publishers don't reject your manuscript because they don't want the controversy or those accusations.

Also, it is fictionally more convenient. You can make the laws whatever you want, as brutal or lenient as you want. You don't have to stick to facts. You can invent new flavors of religions. Nobody can call you out on the culture or laws or history of a fictional country.

If fictional countries bother you, then you are in the minority of fans of fiction. We read fiction because it is made up, we fully expect things to be invented out of whole cloth. We want the characters to be realistic, their setting does not have to be: Look at all the magical fantasy realms, all the scifi realms, all the futuristic Earth stories -- They have emotionally "realistic" heroes and villains, even if they have superpowers, in sometimes wildly creative settings.

But we can relate to what the characters are feeling, the decisions they are making. That is all that counts. I think you are focused on a story element that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Amadeus has listed out several reasons that one would want to write about a fictional country.

There are also several reasons you would want to write about a real country.

- Maybe you want to do a thought experiment with how things would play out in a specific country (that you enjoy researching about) if some conditions were different.
- Or maybe you want to see the dynamics between different familiar countries.
- Maybe working inside the constraints of real countries makes it easier for you to focus on the aspects of story that you are more interested in inventing.
- Maybe you want to make specific points about a particular country.
- Maybe you want to use your extensive knowledge of the real world to your advantage.

At any rate, the answer to your question is YES.

Whether you should or shouldn't write about fictional countries, that just depends on your goals.